# How do you call the line in the middle of a quadrant?

Tags: vectors, terminology

What is the name of the line that starts at $x=0, y=0$, and goes through the following points:

> $x=1, y=1$
>
> $x=2, y=2$
>
> $x=3, y=3$

etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t really a name for the ray you described, but a similar concept is known as the [Identity line](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_line), also known as the 1:1 line or 45 degree line. The difference is because the ray you’re asking has domain $[0, \infty)$, but the identity line has domain $(-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: Strictly speaking, the OP has described a ray, not a line.

Comment: @amd You’re right. I’ve amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think by far the most common name is just "the line $y=x$". (In fact, as amd's comment on another answer points out, you seem to be talking about "the line $y=x$ for $x\geq 0$".)

Comment: What about "diagonal"?